# Сортировка товаров с фото битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Как в каталоге битрикс вывести первыми товар с фотографиями ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Открываем [мануал](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php) и видим:

> `HAS_PREVIEW_PICTURE` и `HAS_DETAIL_PICTURE` - сортировка по наличию и отсутствию картинок.